# Decompiled Sources only show "throw null" for every .NET Framework class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, decompiling

I have

- installed Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.3.3 (including "ASP.NET and Web development" and ".NET Core cross-platform development")
- and have checked "Enable Navigation to decompiled Sources",
- and created a new ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core 3.0.0)

but when I then look at e.g. the decompiled source for any referenced class in the .NET framework e.g. `System.Console` or for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` (or almost any other type), all I can see for every method's body is throw null (I showed an extract below)

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400507/decompiling-net-assemblies-only-shows-throw-null) question (update: and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701135/reference-assemblies-folder-and-different-assemblies-with-the-same-version/9702071#9702071) to the question it was a duplicate to), but there only one class had this problem (because it was added in an incremental update). For me, this problem applies to every class in the .NET framework. What am I doing wrong? Is this expected behaviour and I should use something like dotPeek?
Can I use a symbols server instead of decompiled sources?
(Forgive my ignorance, I'm really new to C#... and the .NET world)

```
region Assembly System.Console, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.0.0\ref\netcoreapp3.0\System.Console.dll
// Decompiled with ICSharpCode.Decompiler 4.0.0.4521
#endregion

using System.IO;
using System.Text;
namespace System
{

// Summary:
// .... 
    public static ConsoleColor BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            throw null;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    //
    // Summary:
    //...
    public static int BufferHeight
    {
        get
        {
            throw null;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9702071/463623) is probably what explaisn what you are seeing. What you are looking at is just a "Reference" assembly, that contains the metadata and type signatures. The actual implementation is somewhere else.

Comment: Hm, I read this answer originally as well (it's linked as the answer to the question above), but there it says that this is the case because the class in question was added in an incremental update. For me, every class is like this. If I'm looking in the wrong location (the reference), how can I make Visual studio look into the correct one?  Alternatively, Is it possible to use a symbols server instead of decompiled sources, like I do when I'm setting a debugging breakpoint?

Comment: So how to find the real assembly? And why not decompile that?

Comment: Actually look at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime implementations can be found there

Comment: You need to find the folder where you installed your runtime. Eg. a path to the authentication dll for builder.Services.AddAuthentication is /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNet.Core.App/6.0.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll then open it with your decompiler (eg. ILSpy in vscode) directly

Comment: @Wouter Did you find a way to do this in VS or VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with ILSpy?

You can use it standalone (free version here: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), but If you have LinqPad, then ILSpy is included (I think in the paid version).

Try it the following way:

1. Create a sample program with 1 line you like to inspect:

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       System.Console.Clear();
   }
   ```
2. With the mouse pointer, set the cursor on "Clear()" and then press F12.
3. ILSpy opens showing the method you set the cursor on:

   ```
    // System.Console
    public static void Clear()
    {
       ConsolePal.Clear();
    }
   ```
4. On the left side you can drill down into further into decompiled classes, e.g.

   ```
    internal static class ConsolePal
    {
        [Flags]
        internal enum ControlKeyState
        {
                    RightAltPressed = 0x1,
                    LeftAltPressed = 0x2,
                    RightCtrlPressed = 0x4,
                    LeftCtrlPressed = 0x8,
                    ShiftPressed = 0x10,
                    NumLockOn = 0x20,
                    ScrollLockOn = 0x40,
                    CapsLockOn = 0x80,
                    EnhancedKey = 0x100
    }

    private sealed class WindowsConsoleStream : ConsoleStream
    {
        private readonly bool _isPipe;

        private IntPtr _handle;
    // ...
   ```

---

**NOTE:** As an alternative to LinqPad, Visual Studio 2022 ships also with decompilation support for F12 enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

The "throw null" behavior you are seeing is due to the fact that the .NET Core framework is built with "ReadyToRun" (R2R) technology, which means that the compiled code is optimized for performance and size. In order to view the decompiled source code of the framework classes, you will need to disable ReadyToRun (R2R) compilation by adding the following line to your .csproj file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>  
  <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

After you have added this line, you will need to unload and reload your project in Visual Studio for the changes to take effect. Once you have done this, you should be able to see the decompiled source code of the framework classes when you navigate to them.